# Aumentando conteúdo da div dinamicamente

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Tenho 3 div's e a div2 deve possuir conteúdo dinâmico (crescendo conforme o conteúdo é inserido nela), a div1 deve acompanhar o crescimento da div2. Como posso fazer isso?

```
    <div id="divPrincipal">
        <div id="div1" style="width:20%; background-color:gray;"></div>
        <div id="div2" style="width:80%"> Conteúdo dinâmico ... </div>
    </div>
```

Alguem tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Você está utilizando algum framework?

Comment: No caso indicado por renan a div ocupa a parte inferior restante, já nesse caso, o objetivo é acompanhar lateralmente. Um cresce de um lado e o outro acompanha do outro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é automático, levei um tempo para aprender. A div principal deve ser Absoluta ou Relativa

```
position:relative;
```

ou

```
position:absolute;
```

e a div 2 deve ser relativa e o todo o conteúdo dentro também. Se não funcionar a culpa pode estar nos elementos ao lado da div principal que devem ser relativos. Evite utilizar width ou height por porcentagem mas pode utilizar width: 100% nos dois div caso o queira que o comprimento do div 1 seja igual ao do div 2 e a div 2 esteja abaixo da div 1. Não se esqueça de utilizar `max-width` e `max-height` com `overflow: auto`

Comment: Era o overflow que estava faltando, obrigado.